# Is Android's freeform app multi-window mode supported on Android Automotive OS?

Tags: multi-window, android-automotive, freeform

Is Android's freeform app multi-window mode supported on android automotive os?

Was not successful in enabling freeform mode on android automotive os after:

1. adding the following to the activity's manifest.xml

```
android:resizeableActivity="true"
```

2. Turning the 'Enable freeform windows' toggle under Developer Settings to ON
3. Configuring height and width of activity layout to be smaller than full screen

Wondering if it's supported and if so, how to enabled it for activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a device supports freeform window management by using [PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManage.FEATURE_FREEFORM_WINDOW_MANAGEMENT)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#FEATURE_FREEFORM_WINDOW_MANAGEMENT).